# Как взаимодействовать с системным календарем android через сайт

Tags: php, android, календарь

Видел, что в bitrix24 через сайт можно создавать события в системном календаре android. Т.е. создаю событие на сайте и оно сразу синхронизируется с системным календарем андроида. Как такое можно реализовать у себя на сайте?

Comment: Это вроде работает через почту - приходит письмо, почтовый клиент видит, что это календарное событие и предлагает его добавить в календарь. могу ошибаться

Answer (score 0):

Подключить к проекту Zend_Gdata, в этой либе есть функции для работы с календарем в том числе. [ссылка на документацию](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/ru/zend.gdata.html)